# Does Vue.js have a built in way to add a copy of a persistent object to a repeated array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue.js app where I have a v-repeat on an array of items. I want to add a newItem to the list of items. When I try `this.items.push(this.newItem)` the object pushed is still bound to the input. Consider the below:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',

  data: {
    items: [
      {
        start: '12:15',
        end: '13:15',
        name: 'Whatch Vue.js Laracast',
        description: 'Watched the Laracast series on Vue.js',
        tags: ['learning', 'Vue.js', 'Laracast', 'PHP'],
        note: "Vue.js is really awesome. Thanks Evan You!!!"
      },
      {
        start: '13:15',
        end: '13:30',
        name: "Rubik's Cube",
        description: "Play with my Rubik's Cube",
        tags: ['Logic', 'Puzzle', "Rubik's Cube"],
        note: "Learned a new algorithm."
      }
    ],
    newItem: {start: '', end: '', name: '', description: '', tags: '', note: ''}
  },

  methods: {
    addItem: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      this.items.push(this.newItem);
    }
  }
});
```

The above will, as expected, push the object that is bound onto the items array. The problem is I want just a copy of the object so it will no longer change when the input changes. See this [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huLygoag/). I know I can do:

```
addItem: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.items.push({
    name:        this.newItem.name,
    start:       this.newItem.start,
    end:         this.newItem.end,
    description: this.newItem.description,
    tags:        this.newItem.tags,
    notes:       this.newItem.notes
  })
}
```

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/huLygoag/1/) but is a lot of repetition.

**The question:** Is there a built in way to add just a copy of the object instead of the persistent object.

Comment: I understand there could be a columns array in data to generate the columns and it's models etc.. Also the tags field isn't kept as an array. I copied this from a project I am starting and half implemented it for an example. Just ignore these.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/158) on GitHub.

**Shallow Clone**

I was using jQuery's `$.extend` until [Evan You](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1070244/evan-you) pointed out there is an undocumented built it extend function `Vue.util.extend` that does a shallow clone. So what you could use is:

```
addItem: function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.items.push(Vue.util.extend({}, this.newItem));
}
```

See the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huLygoag/2/).

**Deep Clone**

When doing a shallow clone on an object that references other objects you copy the references to the external objects instead of cloning them. To clone the object completely do a **Deep Clone**.

For the deep clone, per Evan's suggestion in the first link, one could use: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))`. This can be seen between [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ke9yf4pj/) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ke9yf4pj/1/).

If using lodash check out [lodash cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#cloneDeep). If using NPM check out [clone-deep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep).

Comment: Evan's comment on that issue states that it is a shallow clone. Only the top level properties are cloned.

Comment: i tried clone-deep and it's working fine. I just wanted to make sure I have a sort of snapshot copy of an obj that had a vue component in there and _.cloneDeep and most libs and functions don't work well, but clone-deep did it for me.

Comment: I fixed clone-deep so it handles circular references, see https://github.com/emahuni/clone-deep.git

Comment: This article was a good read: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-best-way-to-deep-copy-an-object-in-javascript--cms-39655

Answer (score 16):

This didn't work for me (vue 1.0.13). I used the following to create a copy without the data bindings:

```
this.items.push( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( newItem ) ) );
```

Comment: I meant DutGRIFF's answer: 
`this.items.push(Vue.util.extend({}, this.newItem));`

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE 2024:**

You should use [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) to clone removing the objects references:

```js
  addItem: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    this.items.push(structuredClone(this.newItem));
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also use Object Spread:

```js
  addItem: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    this.items.push({...this.newItem});
  }
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

You can use Vanilla JavaScript with Object.assign():

```js
  addItem: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.items.push(Object.assign({}, this.newItem));
  }
```

Comment: `Object.assign` creates a shallow copy. I am assuming that the object spread also creates a shallow copy, right?

Comment: Not a deep. Make this simple test: 
a =  {
    nivel1: {
        nivel2: {
            nivel3: 'nivel 3'
        }
    },
    
}
b = a 
b.nivel1.nivel2.nivel3 = 'new value' 
a.nivel1.nivel2.nivel3 // 'new value'

Answer (score 4):

The top answer is wrong. Vue.util.extend has nothing to do with jQuery's extend. It's always a shallow clone. 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1849#issuecomment-158770874

Object.assign and Spread operator are also shallow copy. see this https://scotch.io/bar-talk/copying-objects-in-javascript

Simply use the implementation of Ramda.js 
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/v0.26.1/source/internal/_clone.js

_curry is not necessary if you don't want them.

Or check this MVA [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?page=2&tab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

[structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) can be used but there is a little gotcha. It cannot clone an Proxy which is the way Vue 3 implements reactivity. So you must first get the target and clone this:

```js
import { toRaw } from 'vue'
...
const someCopy = structuredClone(toRaw(someObject))
```