# Vuejs Saving Data

Tags: javascript, state, vue.js, data-objects

I have a fairly complex app which take the user through a 5-step process. I have a data object called userData which contains all their entry info (name, age, weight, heigh,etc).

At a certain point in the app I would like to take a snapshot of this data, and recall it if I need to. If I write it to a new var in the data object, it is dynamic. I want to create a static copy or snapshot of the data at stage 5.

How can I achieve this?

I have looked at

http://rc.vuejs.org/guide/application.html#State_Management

but maybe does not seem the way to go.

Comment: You might want to look at using something like http://vuejs.github.io/vuex/ . Failing that you could just declare an object outside of the component's scope. One issue you might bump into is has been addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578254/does-vue-js-have-a-built-in-way-to-add-a-copy-of-a-persistent-object-to-a-repeat

Comment: thanks Ross, heard a bit about Vuex looks interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you just need to store a static copy of the data at that point in time, you can simply use any javascript method: `Object.assign()` and store the variable in your data prop or if it doesn't need to be bound to the template, in your $options

```
this.$options.userCache = Object.assign({}, this.userData)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign