# Confuse in list rendering when add remove action in Vuejs

Tags: arrays, scope, vuejs2

I have a array of quote items that created dynamically by user. By default there is an item in list. When I click on new item, a null object `push` to array. Until now every things is OK, but when I add 3rd record, 2nd and 3rd record confuse to each other and every things that change in 3rd record as real time apply to 2nd record. It's my sample code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXZLZy

**This problem has raised after adding the deletion function**

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are pushing a copy of the same object on the list - so you need to copy/clone it, otherwise it will just be a reference to the same object. This seems to be the easiest way to do so:

```
        this.quote_items.push(Vue.util.extend({}, this.newItem));
```

Comment: I guess it's a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578254/does-vue-js-have-a-built-in-way-to-add-a-copy-of-a-persistent-object-to-a-repeat

Answer (score 0):

My problem because of `newItem` variable that `push` to array. I change this code:

```
this.quote_items.push(this.newItem);
```

to

```
this.quote_items.push({
            inventory_id: '',
            count: 1,
            fee: 13500000,
            discount: 0,
            sum: 0,
            tax_percent: 9,
            tax_amount: 0,
            total: 0
        });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXZLZy?editors=1010