# Vue.js Why 2 objects are linked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two data objects called items and itemsOrg

```
var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#divVM',
      mixins: [mix],     
      data: {
            items: [],
            itemsOrg:[],
            // ....
           },
```

When the page loads, I make an AJAX call to fetch data from MySQL table and assign it to **items** and **itemsOrg** object.

```
function getMustacheVariables()
{
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "adminAjax.php", 
        data: { 
            actionID: 'GET_DATA', 
        },
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(data) 
        {
            vm.items= data; 
            vm.itemsOrg = data;
        }
        // ...
```

However, when I update Vm.items, vm.itemsOrg is also automatically updated and don't know why these the two are linked. Here is a snapshot of console.log

```
vm.items[0]["key"] 
"agent"
vm.itemsOrg[0]["key"]
"agent"
vm.items[0]["key"] = "new_key"
"new_key"
vm.itemsOrg[0]["key"]
"new_key"
vm.itemsOrg[0]["key"] = "updated_key"
"updated_key"
vm.items[0]["key"] 
"updated_key"
```

Is there a reason that these two objects are linked? I even tried assigning vm.items to vm.itemsOrg using **vm.items.slice()** as well as **push()** but the two objects are always linked.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: you're assinging data for both. what you expect?

Comment: There was a typo error in my original post. Please see updated code.

Comment: i'm still seeing the same.

Comment: `vm.items= data; vm.itemsOrg = data;` means both variables are now references to the same object.  You'll want to [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578254/does-vue-js-have-a-built-in-way-to-add-a-copy-of-a-persistent-object-to-a-repeat) `data` instead of simply assigning the other variables as equal to it.

Comment: Try using `[...data]` for arrays, or `{...data}` for objects.

Comment: My requirements is to initially assign the same data to two objects, Later when the user updates data in vm.items, I want vm.itemsOrg to stay the same (originally loaded data) so that I may compare if user has updated any data on the page.

Comment: What if you try: `vm.items.concat(data); vm.itemsOrg.concat(data)` ?

Comment: @PaulCo: contact(data) does not work as data is object.

Comment: @m3characters: I tried vm.items= data; vm.itemsOrg = {...data}; but still when I change vm.items, vm.itemsOrg changes,

Comment: Probably when you change an item, you'll want to spread it into a new item, so that it's not referencing the same object. so first `vm.itemsOrg = [...data]`, then when changing a specific item `vm.items[0] = {...vm.items[0], key: "test" }`, but you might be more interested in this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript/5344074#5344074 - as this is not a vuejs issue, but just how js works. In jquery, it works because you use `true`as the first param to extend, which executes a deep copy with new references.

Comment: So it seems that `data = { 0: {key: 'agent'})`, if you're declaring `vm.items = []` and then putting `vm.items = data` you are shifting from a table to an object... If data is indeed an [Array-like Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object) then you could try `vm.items = Array.from(data)` in ES6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing with your example I noticed that we can simplify your AJAX fetched object as `data = { 0: { key: 'agent'}` and it has this property `data[0]` assigned to a reference of the object `{ key: 'agent'}` (`data` can be called a nested object)

So it seems that even if you're copying the `data` object with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) you'll still have every referenced object in it. As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object#answer-728694) :

> But be aware that this makes a shallow copy only. Nested objects are still copied as references.

So you have two options that would work **without JQuery**:

**1.** Using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` to stringify then parse your object

**2.** Making a loop to manually deep copy the object (as in the outdated answer of the thread referenced above)

And if **using JQuery** you can write [`jQuery.extend(true ,{}, data)`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) with the `deep` option set to `true`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a reason here. this code means that's vm.items and vm.itemsOrg are the same ref (data).

use chrome devtools to see the Trace

```
    vm.items= data; 
    vm.itemsOrg = data;
```

Comment: Ok. I understand that the same data is assigned (referenced) to vm.items and vm.itemsOrg. What is the best way to make a static copy of the 'data' object in vm.itemsOrg which does not change when vm.items changes,  {...data} did not help.

Comment: Try this :
`vm.itemsOrg = Object.assign({}, vm.items);`

Comment: @ Abderrahim Soubai Elidrissi:  vm.itemsOrg = Object.assign({}, vm.items); does not work. However,   vm.itemsOrg = jQuery.extend(true, {}, vm.items);  works

Comment: Enjoy it's same main idea just like Object.assign ;)